# Transform both axes in tikz, plot f(x,y) vs g(x,y) where x, and y are Cartesian axis

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, tikz-datavisualization

It is easy to do with `\addplot3` but I want a 2d plot.

I want to plot a scatter plot: `g(x,y)` value on vertical axis and `f(x,y)` on horizontal axis. AFAIK, The parametric plot syntax allows only one axis value as its argument e.g. [How to plot functions like ‎‎‎‎‎x=f(y)‎‎ using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105570/how-to-plot-functions-like-x-fy-using-tikz)

Any solution which uses `tikz-datavisualization`, `pgfplot` or `gnuplot` is fine.

Comment: Did you try `\addplot` with keys `x expr`, `y expr` ?

Comment: @percusse Thanks. I was bit successful with `datavisualization` library using `func x` and `func y`. I'll try now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it using both `pgfplot` and `tikz-datavisualization`. Though pgfplot solution is better.

## Pgfplot solution

```
% create a new table with 10 rows and columns 'x' and 'y':
\pgfplotstablenew
[
    % define how the 'new' column shall be filled:
    create on use/x/.style ={ create col/expr ={100*rand}},
    create on use/y/.style ={ create col/expr ={100*rand}},
    columns={x,y}
] {1000} \mydata
% show it:
%\pgfplotstabletypeset\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1
    , every node/.style={}
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$||x|-|y||$,ylabel=$|x+y|$
    ]
        \addplot[ only marks, color = blue ] table [
            , x expr=abs(abs(\thisrowno{0}) - abs(\thisrowno{1}))
            , y expr=abs(\thisrowno{0}+\thisrowno{1})
        ] {\mydata};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: pgfplot solution. I could get random sampling easily using <code>pgfplotstables</code>]

## `tikz-datavisualization` solution

Almost same but could not get random sampling of interval.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1 , every node/.style={} ]
    \datavisualization[
       scientific axes=clean, visualize as scatter
       , scatter={
           style={mark=*
               , mark options={color=blue,mark size=2pt} } 
           }
    ]
    data[ format=function ] {
        var i : interval [-100:100];
        var j : interval [-100:100];
        func y = abs(\value i + \value j) ;
        func x = abs( abs(\value i) - abs(\value j) );
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: <code>tikz-datavisualization</code> solution. I could not get random sampling between interval.]