# How to plot graph of a function restricting the domain in the set of Natural number for beamer?

Tags: diagrams, graphs

I want to plot f(n)=n+sin(n)function restricting the domain in the set of natural numbers. I need the code for beamer presentation. Is there any software that would generate the graph as well as export the code. Please help me how can i do this ( Explaination in non technical language is welcome)

Comment: maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105570/how-to-plot-functions-like-x-fy-using-tikz can give you some starting points

Comment: I assume, that you like to draw in LaTeX ... In this case you first need select package by which you will draw your graph (`tikz`, `pgfplots`, `pstricks`, ...). Then you should define domain of your function and look for examples of graphs drawn with selected package. Drawing with any of mentioned package is independent from document class.

Comment: well i can understand to get a graph but how to restrict on N?

Answer (score 1):

With `pgfplots` you can decide which x-values you want the function calculated for with the `samples at` key, and you plot only markers with the `only marks` key.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=Radians,ylabel=$n+\sin(n)$]
\addplot [samples at={0,...,20},only marks] {x +sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```