# How to draw ROC plan with horizontal and vertical legends?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I would like to know how to make an axis identical to the one in the picture with all captions and grids.

[image]

I have tried a few ways, but I can't make it. If someone can help me it would be great

Comment: I'd say this image came from Matlab. In the manual of [pgfplots](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), check sections 4.2 and 4.16.

Comment: I would like to draw this image using latex, because I don't have access to MatLAB and don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the basics of the default style from Matlab (I'm also a user, so I recognized the style). I let colors in the following example in order to make clear where each style goes. You may change them to black or just remove them.

The key concept is to edit `<property> style={keys}`. Please check:

- https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces

to find the font of your preference. I let `\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont`, as I *think* Helvetica (almost equal to Arial) is the closest font style. Just change the three letter in `\fontfamily` to change fontstyle.

If your are willing to plot other functions, check

- https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf
- [How to plot functions like ‎‎‎‎‎x=f(y)‎‎ using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105570/how-to-plot-functions-like-x-fy-using-tikz)
- https://latexdraw.com/plot-a-function-and-data-in-latex/

you may also plot data from tables and external data files.

A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    tick style={grid=major, very thick},
    title style={font=\LARGE\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries, color=green!50!black},
    tick label style={font=\small\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries, color=red},
    label style={font=\small\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries, color=blue},
    xmin=0, xmax = 1,
    ymin=0, ymax = 1,
    xtick={0,0.1,...,1}, ytick={0,0.1,...,1},
    xlabel={1 - espeficidade},
    ylabel={Sensibilidade},
    title={Title},
    ]
    \addplot[blue, ultra thick] {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Diego Freire and Welcome to TeX.SE (Saudações do Brasil).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!