# help with a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Hi guys I wanted to do the following plot using `tikz`.[image]

Can you help me replicate this picture? I'd prefer not to use `pgfplots` instead I'd like to use the \draw plot function. The plotted equation sounds like this `$y=v_{exit}ln(M_0/m})$`.

Comment: Possible *duplicate*: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105570

Comment: I would still go with `pgfplots` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Do you understand that "the course" has no meaning to me?! :) And if it is homework that this is maybe not the right forum or at least state it in the question if this is the case.

Comment: A good start is the excellent manual (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Chapter 79 "Introduction to Data Visualization" explains the concept.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `TikZ` solution.

[image]

The actual scale of the graph is from 0 to 5 on the x-axis and 0 to 9 on the y-axis. The labels are calculated accordingly. The `xscale` and `yscale` settings are for appearance only, so that the graph is 10cm wide (with `xscale` set at 2) and 7.2cm high (with `y-scale` set at .8). Of course  you can change the values of `xscale` and `yscale` however you like to best fit your document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2,yscale=.8,font=\sffamily]
\draw[gray!50] (0,9)--(0,0) (-.1,0)node[black,left]{0}--(5,0)--(5,9);
\foreach \y in {2,4,...,18}{\draw[gray!50](-.1,\y/2)node[black,left]{\y\,000}--(5,\y/2);}
\foreach \x in {0,5,...,25}{\draw[gray!50](\x/5,-.1)node[black,below]{\x}--(\x/5,0);}
\foreach \v/\c[count=\n,evaluate=\v as \l using int(\v*1000)] 
    in {1/red,1.5/orange,2/yellow,3/green,4/blue,5/violet}{
    \draw[ultra thick, \c, domain=.2:5, smooth, variable=\x] plot (\x, {.5*\v*ln(5*\x)});
    \draw[ultra thick, \c](5.2,7-\n/1.5)--(5.8,7-\n/1.5)node[black,right]{\l};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: For clarification "`actual scale is from 0 to 5`" refers to the physical paper dimensions (cm by default AFAIK) AND the diagram units, correct?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Physical paper dimensions of the graph are affected by `xscale` and `yscale`. I'll try to make my explanation more clear.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I edited my response. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Very good, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- A starting point using `pgfplots`.
- I do not plan to replicate the picture but the OP can use the code below as a start.

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = {$a \cdot \ln(x)$},
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 25,
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
    ]
    % Plot 1
    \addplot[
        domain = 1:25, 
        samples = 201,
        smooth,
        color = blue,
        ] {10*ln(x)};
        \addlegendentry{$a = 10$}
    % Plot 2
    \addplot[
        domain = 1:25, 
        samples = 201,
        smooth,
        color = red,
        ] {20*ln(x)};
        \addlegendentry{$a = 20$}       
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]
*(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation)*